# Can you pass table input parameter to SQL Server from Python

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

MS SQL Server supports passing a table as a stored-procedure parameter.  Is there any way to utilize this from Python, using PyODBC or pymssql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use IronPython.  It allows direct access to the .net framework, and therefore you can build a DataTable object and pass it over.

Answer (score 4):

There may be a way to do so using a more API-ey feature, but if all else fails you could just use whatever the API exposes to send raw SQL commands to build the tables yourself and call the procedure, using a query string like the following:

```
DECLARE @p1 <TableTypeName>;
INSERT @p1 VALUES (<value list...>);    
EXEC usp_Procedure @p1;
```